# Return row for session PHP

Tags: php, session

I would like to be able to read the account type from a row and return it with the `$session` name. Let's say I have a table called "accounts", with two columns for the user name and account type. When the user logs in and if it is successful it will start a session. This is the current code:

```
if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password && $row['type']=="Advanced") {
    $_SESSION['userAdvanced'] = $row['userId'];
    header("Location: index.php");
```

However I would like to make it so I can have something like this:

```
if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password) {
    $_SESSION['user'+[type]] = $row['userId'];
    header("Location: index.php");
```

So that it will return "userAdvanced".

I would also like to be able to have multiple `$session` types in one if statement. I have tried this but it did not work: (Instead of having two separate if statements merge them into one).

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userBasic'],['userAdvanced'])){ ?>
  <a class="link" href="/index.php?logout" style="text-decoration:none">Logout</a>
```

Apologies if this does not make much sense, Please let me know what to do to improve the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you could just do this

```java
if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password) {
    $_SESSION['user' . $row['type']] = $row['userId'];
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

And for the second one, you can define a function to do that for you.

```java
function checkUserType(array $types) {
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if (isset($_SESSION('user' . $type))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

<?php if(checkUserType(['Basic', 'Advanced'])): ?>
    <a class="link" href="/index.php?logout" style="text-decoration:none">Logout</a>
<?php endif ?>
```